# playframework scala slick how to update one single attribute

Tags: scala, playframework

Hi I want to update only one value of an model and store it to database.

I try this:

```
  def updateProcessTemplateApproveProcessId(processTemplate: ProcessTemplatesModel, approveProcessInstanceId: Int): Future[Int] = {

    val action = for {
      processTemplatesUpdate <- processTemplates if processTemplatesUpdate.id === processTemplate.id // WHERE Statement
    } yield processTemplatesUpdate.approveProcessInstance = Some(approveProcessInstanceId) // SELECT Statement

    db.run(action.update(Some(true)))
  }
```

But I got error reassignment to val is not allowed ... thats correct ;) so I changed the attribute in model to var.

```
case class ProcessTemplatesModel(
                                  id: Option[Int] = None,
                                  title: String,
                                  version: String,
                                  createdat: Option[String],
                                  updatedat: Option[String],
                                  deadline: Option[Date],
                                  status: Option[String],
                                  comment: Option[String],
                                  checked: Option[Boolean],
                                  checkedat: Option[Date],
                                  approved: Option[Boolean],
                                  approvedat: Option[Date],
                                  deleted: Boolean,
                                  approveprocess: Int,
                                  trainingsprocess: Option[Int],
                                  previousVersion: Option[Int],
                                  originTemplate: Option[Int],
                                  client: Int,
                                  var approveProcessInstance: Option[Int],
```

Whats my fil in this case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change your case class. Assuming that `processTemplates` is a `TableQuery`, do the following instead:

```
val query = for {
  processTemplatesUpdate <- processTemplates if processTemplatesUpdate.id === processTemplate.id
} yield processTemplatesUpdate.approveProcessInstance

val action = query.update(Some(approveProcessInstanceId))
db.run(action)
```

Comment: Just wondering, should we use `for comp` for only one statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one liner (Assuming that `processTemplates` is a `TableQuery` object)

```
db.run(processTemplates.filter(_.id === processTemplate.id).map(_. approveProcessInstanceId).update(Some(true)))
```

Hope this helps.